# I need some help understanding the schematics of DIY HS102 oscilloscope

Tags: circuit-analysis, schematics

I was looking on the schematics for the DIY HS102 oscilloscope by Martin Loren (http://hscope.martinloren.com/HS102-oscilloscope.html)

But I'm a bit confused about the role of the ASM1117 (LDO regulator ASM1117-1.2). it seems that the output is not used, so what's the point of having it?

[image]

Comment: That's a bit of a red flag: The author of that web page doesn't have an *actual* schematic (what you've posted are *wiring diagrams*, not a schematic, but the first one is relatively close to being a schematic, albeit not drawn in a way that makes it easy to understand), and it has blatant illogicalities. So, my guess is, Martin Loren just copied parts of a different design he didn't fully understand, OR he's "abusing" the ASM1117 as some kind of reverse voltage protection without telling us why he can do that. I'd recommend finding the original thing and using that.

Comment: I say that because this circuit is definitely not designed with even the most basic oscilloscope theory in mind – there's bandlimiting missing on the input, so you'll see aliasing all over the place, and unless what you observe with that oscilloscope is already sufficiently low-pass filtered, you simply won't see what you should be seeing.

Comment: Hi Marcus. I'm not expecting it to be a professional oscilloscope. If it can display the signal of a simple "blinky" like circuit i'm more than happy :)

Comment: If you follow the right links from that site, you end up [here.](https://github.com/SUNsung/HScope_PCB/blob/master/H102/HScope_2018_10_L.pdf)  That's a schematic of hardwarw built for the same project.  It appears to use diodes instead of that jiggery-pokery with the 1117 regulator.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that the intent is to create an offset ground reference for the probes so that the one-sided (0 - 3.3V) measurement of the A-D can accommodate the +/-5V input claimed. The resistive dividers reduce that input down to +/-1.6V relative to the center point of the supply.

The setup of the firmware includes a step to ground the probes and calibrate the zero level, which would then subtract that offset from the input measurement, allowing a proper bipolar representation of the input voltage.

Obviously the regulator isn't configured correctly to do that  - there are a couple of resistors missing from the adjustment and the pinout is incorrect. It could be replaced by another 1k resistor and leave the circuit to function well enough with just a resistive divider, but there'd be a risk of the "Probe GND" suffering a small offset from a DC input on the probes, the regulator if it were functioning would minimize that.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I agree that the 1.2V regulator's output is not used, even on the drawing of the prototype board there's nothing connected to pin 2 (which is the output).

So the LDO only loads the 3.3 V line with it's quiescent current consumption.

I also see no reason why it is there. Removing it should not change anything.

Perhaps the author first thought he needed a 1.2 V and then later discovered that he didn't. Or indeed as Marcus suggests in the comments: the author didn't have a clue and just copied the design including superfluous components.